# issue with the installation of the pyeeg library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I had used a pip install to install the pyeeg library, the code to which is as follows(installing the package in the jupyter notebook environment using ! before the pip install statement):

```
pip install pyeeg
```

The package and its other associated dependencies get installed, but when trying to import the library, the code to which is as follows:

```
import pyeeg
```

The following error is displayed:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyeeg'
```

I've tried installing the library in user mode too, but the same error gets displayed

I've also tried downloading the respective source code file and placing it in my directory path, but the file seems to be having an issue.

Looking for some help in this regard.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation can be done as specified in the [main repo](https://github.com/forrestbao/pyeeg). The steps are as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/forrestbao/pyeeg.git

cd pyeeg
python setup.py install

python setup.py install --user
```